# confirm wiring question

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I'm replacing a light fixture in my house and I want to be sure I'm doing it right. here's the diagram for the new fixture: [image]

and here's what's going on in my ceiling:
[image]

I assume I'm connecting black to black, white to white, and striped (it's green/yellow) to the green screw? I took a picture of how the previous light was wired but they had the green wire just tucked up there loose (sorry for the blurriness):
[image]
and that doesn't seem right - or safe

Comment: Your connections seem right, but I would snip the bare copper back to the insulation and stripe the insulation a 1/2 inch for new copper.  The copper showing looks chewed up.  Turn the breaker off first, do not trust the switch alone.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for the tips, the breaker is definitely off

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to have an equipment grounding conductor with your supply wires. In that case (unless that metal box is grounded by metal conduit or some such), the green/yellow wire from your fixture has no function, and you may as well leave it unconnected. The green screw in your photo would presumably go away when you remove that existing mounting strap and use the one supplied with your fixture, as illustrated. Here in the U.S., it would not be permissible to install a light fixture with exposed conductive (metal) parts to such an ungrounded outlet box.